# list of floats in python

Tags: python, list, range

I want to create a list of all floats from -100 to 100 with step of 0.1 but it shows an error.

```
nums = [range(-100, 100, 0.1)]

    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    nums = [*range(-100, 100, 0.5)]
TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

Please help!

Comment: Check the docs: https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=range#range
`The arguments to the range constructor must be integers`

Comment: The `step` must be an integer.